# Delay in wpf drawing

Tags: c#, wpf

I wrote this class as a test to see how fast WPF draws. It set as the child element of the window.

```
internal class TestElement : UIElement
{
    private readonly Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
    private int frames = 0;

    public TestElement()
    {
        this.st.Start();
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += (sender, args) =>
                                       {
                                           this.frames++;
                                           if (this.st.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 1000)
                                           {
                                               Debug.WriteLine(this.frames);
                                               this.frames = 0;
                                               this.st.Restart();
                                           }
                                           this.InvalidateVisual();
                                       };
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Red, null, Mouse.GetPosition(this), 5, 5);
    }
}
```

It takes 0 ms to `InvalidateVisual`. Also, the framerate is 60 most of the times. However, I see a considerable delay in drawing the ellipse to the screen. It seems to be following the mouse too far behind. Here's a video:

https://youtu.be/xFzaSjxQVcg

Clearly, it does not look like 60fps. What would be the cause?

Comment: But if visual was invalidated by InvalidateVisual - does not mean it was already redrawn.

Comment: I know, but it shows fps as 60..

Comment: From the [Threading Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) article on MSDN: *Typically, WPF applications start with two threads: one for handling rendering and another for managing the UI. The rendering thread effectively runs hidden in the background while the UI thread receives input, handles events, paints the screen, and runs application code.* The OnRender method (and also the Rendering event handler) is called in the application's UI thread, while the visual output is generated by the rendering thread, which may lag behind.

Comment: @Clemens, thank you. I guess I will have to go with the lag. It's acceptable for the application I am using it anyway